# Aligning div and navbar to the right using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, alignment

I have a html code right:

https://jsfiddle.net/zdwkvp3c/3/

I want to align the heading on left and dropdown and the `ul` ( Bar and Trend) on right, when on big screens\medium screens.

I want to align the heading on left and dropdown and ul ( Bar and Trend) on right, but this time, dropdown will be on top and `ul` ( Bar and Trend) below the dropdown, but both of these should be towards the right.

I have used nested rows and unable to get pull-right work. Kindly let me know if I am missing something in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do not exactly understand what you want to achieve ( your instructions are not clear ) but take a look at the snippet below. is this what you want ?

or [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zdwkvp3c/5/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 header pull-left" style="background: green">
 By Companies
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-right"  style="background: blue">
    <div class="row inner_row">
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin">
            <select style="width:100%;">
                    <option>DropdownVal1</option>
                    
                </select>
        </div>
       
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin" style="background: orange">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right" style="float:right;">
                <li>
                    <a>Bar Chart</a>
                </li>
  <li>
                    <a>Line Chart</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
  </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mihai. Just to make clear to you, this is what i want to achieve:

https://pasteboard.co/g0Ks0csIZ.png


Same design, based on bootstrap grid column:
https://pasteboard.co/g0E1Se75e.png

Comment: @Deepak edited my answer with a new solution. check it here > https://jsfiddle.net/zdwkvp3c/5/ ( resize the window to see )

Comment: Thanks Mihai. It worked well for sm and xs, however the dropdown was appearing in the middle of the screen, instead of aligning on the right. For that, this solved my problem:  https://www.bootply.com/121984